# How + internally works on Strings in JAVA

Tags: java, string

I read from the blogs that internally java use StringBuilder to concat the String when we use **+** operator. I was just checking it and found some strange outputs.

```
public class StringDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a = "Hello World";
        String b = "Hello World";
        String c = "Hello";
        String d =  c + " World".intern();
        String e =  new StringBuilder().append(String.valueOf(c)).append(" World").toString().intern() ;
        String f =  new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(c)).append(" World").toString().intern();

        System.out.println(a == b);   // Line 1 Expected output true
        System.out.println(a == d);   // Line 2 Output is false
        System.out.println(a == e);   // Line 3 Output is true
        System.out.println(a == f);   // Line 4 Output is true

    }
}
```

So i am using **+** operator to concat two strings **c** & **" World"** and then use intern() method to move String in the pool for String **d**.

As per my understanding java use StringBuilder, so now I use StringBuilder to concat the String and use intern() method for Strings **e** and **f**.
So if both the equivalent then address of both the String must be same but the output of Line 2 not matching with Line 4 & 5.

Thanks in advance for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 10):

> How + internally works in JAVA

Here is my post on the same, give a read [Compiler version : How String concatenation works in java.](http://codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/08/compiler-version-string-concatenation.html)

And coming to your code inside

```
System.out.println(a == d);
```

That should be `false` only.

As per your understanding you are expecting `true`. No. Your understanding is wrong. There is a clear difference between

```
    String d =  c + " World".intern();
```

And

```
    String d =  (c + " World").intern();
```

In first line only `"World"` got interned and the second line `"Hello World"` got interned

When you do `(c + " World").intern()`, you'll see the output `true`.

Comment: Shit, small mistake. Thanks Suresh